# Coq: destruct (co)inductive hypothesis without losing information

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Consider the following development:

```
Require Import Relation RelationClasses.

Set Implicit Arguments.

CoInductive stream (A : Type) : Type :=
| scons : A -> stream A -> stream A.

CoInductive stream_le (A : Type) {eqA R : relation A}
                      `{PO : PartialOrder A eqA R} :
                      stream A -> stream A -> Prop :=
| le_step : forall h1 h2 t1 t2, R h1 h2 ->
            (eqA h1 h2 -> stream_le t1 t2) ->
            stream_le (scons h1 t1) (scons h2 t2).
```

If I have a hypothesis `stream_le (scons h1 t1) (scons h2 t2)`, it would be reasonable for the `destruct` tactic to turn it into a pair of hypotheses `R h1 h2` and `eqA h1 h2 -> stream_le t1 t2`. But that's not what happens, because `destruct` loses information whenever doing anything non-trivial. Instead, new terms `h0`, `h3`, `t0`, `t3` are introduced into the context, with no recall that they are respectively equal to `h1`, `h2`, `t1`, `t2`.

I would like to know if there is a quick and easy way to do this kind of "smart `destruct`". Here is what i have right now:

```
Theorem stream_le_destruct : forall (A : Type) eqA R
  `{PO : PartialOrder A eqA R} (h1 h2 : A) (t1 t2 : stream A),
  stream_le (scons h1 t1) (scons h2 t2) ->
  R h1 h2 /\ (eqA h1 h2 -> stream_le t1 t2).
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct H eqn:Heq.
  remember (scons h1 t1) as s1 eqn:Heqs1;
  remember (scons h2 t2) as s2 eqn:Heqs2;
  destruct H;
  inversion Heqs1; subst; clear Heqs1;
  inversion Heqs2; subst; clear Heqs2.
  split; assumption.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, `inversion` basically does what you want, however as Arthur pointed out it is a bit unstable, mainly due to the different congruence steps.

Under the hood, `inversion` just calls a version of `destruct`, but remembering some equalities first. As you have well discovered, pattern matching in Coq will "forget" arguments of constructors, except if these are variables, then, all the variables *under the scope* of the destruct will be instantiated.

What does that mean? It means that in order to properly destruct an inductive `I : Idx -> Prop`, you want to get your goal of the form: `I x -> Q x`, so that destructing the `I x` will also refine the `x` in `Q`. Thus, a standard transformation for an inductive `I term` and goal `Q (f term)` is to rewrite it to `I x -> x = term -> Q (f x)`. Then, destructing `I x` will get you `x` instantiated to the proper index.

With that in mind, it may be a good exercise to implement inversion manually using the `case:` tactic of Coq 8.7;

```
From Coq Require Import ssreflect.
Theorem stream_le_destruct A eqA R `{PO : PartialOrder A eqA R} (h1 h2 : A) (t1 t2 : stream A) :
  stream_le (scons h1 t1) (scons h2 t2) ->
  R h1 h2 /\ (eqA h1 h2 -> stream_le t1 t2).
Proof.
move E1: (scons h1 t1) => sc1; move E2: (scons h2 t2) => sc2 H.
by case: sc1 sc2 / H E1 E2 => h1' h2' t1' t2' hr ih [? ?] [? ?]; subst.
Qed.
```

You can read the manual for more details, but basically with the first line, we create the equalities we need; then, in the second we can destruct the term and get the proper instantiations solving the goal. A good effect of the `case:` tactic is that, contrary to destruct, it will try to prevent us from destructing a term without first bringing its dependencies into scope.

Comment: Nice answer, I upvoted. Congrats on hitting 3K by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `destruct` will not directly give you what you want.  You need to use `inversion` instead.

```
Theorem stream_le_destruct : forall h1 h2 t1 t2,
  stream_le (scons h1 t1) (scons h2 t2) ->
  h1 <= h2 /\ (h1 = h2 -> stream_le t1 t2).
Proof.
  intros.
  inversion H; subst; clear H.
  split; assumption.
Qed.
```

Unfortunately, the `inversion` tactic is quite ill behaved, as it tends to generate a lot of spurious equality hypotheses, making it hard to name them consistently.  One (somewhat heavyweight, admittedly) alternative is to use `inversion` only to prove a lemma like the one you did, and apply this lemma in proofs instead of calling `inversion`.